# How does postfix work together with dovecot?

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I am running postfix and dovecot with virtual domains as described in the section "Postfix virtual ALIAS example: separate domains, UNIX system accounts" [here](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html).

After i had set up dovecot logging i always got the error `... temporary failure. Command output: Can't open log file /var/log/dovecot.log: Permission denied` in the postfix log. I found out that this could be solved if i comment out the line with `mailbox_command` in the main.cf. Now i have a few questions:

1. I guess this is because the `mailbox_command` (in my case dovecot) is run as the recipient of the mail but my dovecot logfile is only writeable by root?
2. Why does this error show up in the postfix log? Is it because postfix runs dovecot (defined by `mailbox_command`) and dovecot returns that error which is then written to the postfix log?
3. At the moment i haven't defined `mailbox_transport` or `mailbox_command` in main.cf. They are now empty (by default). Why is the transport still working? It seems that postfix still knows it has to use dovecot as LDA.
4. How does postfix work together with dovecot? Does postfix only rely on the `mailbox_command` and `mailbox_transport` settings?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
chown vmail:mail /var/log/dovecot*
```

I had this problem using Logrotate with wrong definition, it recreated log files with root:root.